# How to insert a line in vim

Tags: python, gvim

In my python application i need to write import `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` for debugging.
And after debugging line is removed.

Is there any way in gvim to insert this line by key mapping, so that i have not to type it every time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `.vimrc`:

```
command D :normal iimport pdb; pdb.set_trace()^V ESC
```

Note:

1. That is indeed two `i`s. Essentially this command does everything that you do when manually entering that text (press <kbd>i</kbd> to start insert mode, type the remaining text, etc.).
2. The `^V ESC` means: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to get into verbatim mode, and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This will enter `Esc` as a character (visible as `^[`).

Now, in you can go to command mode and use the `D` command to have this text inserted:

```
:D
```

You can also map this to a normal mode shortcut, perhaps.

Instead of `^V ESC`, which will bring you out of insert mode, you can add `^V Enter` (same thing, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd>) to go to a new line and remain in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
if has('gui_running')
    function EnableDebug()
        let text="import pdb; pdb.set_trace()"
        0put =text
    endfunction
    nnoremap <leader>d :call EnableDebug()<CR>
endif
```

Then in normal mode, typing `\d` will add the line to top of your file.